# Issue w/Excel Date Column on Import to SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am trying to import an Excel spreadsheet. The date columns keep appearing as numbers. How to I correct this issue at this stage? DateTime is not an option in the dropdown.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here are my steps.

1.Excel file.

[image]

2.In the SharePoint.
[image]

[image]

===================================

If the answer is helpful, please click "√" on the left panel of the answer and kindly upvote it.

Comment: I’m checking how the things are going on about this issue. Whether the answer helps you? If there is any problem with this issue, feel free to let me know.

Comment: The issue is 'Date and Time' is not an option in the dropdown. It's the first thing I looked for, but it was not an option to change the column to at upload as you show in your image.

Thoughts?